# Accessing on single instance of a WCF Service

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I've created my very first WCF service in VB.NET, which is hosted by an external IIS-Server. I want to access this service from different points in my main application. The main application is used by different users and is running on multiple computers.

The instances of the mainapplication shall use the WCF service among others to share data. For example, a List(Of T) is created at a certain point and is used at another point or by another instance of the main application. I think of only one single instance of the service running on an external IIS, which is used by multiple users (applications/computers).

This is, what I did. I created an Interface called IemmbeeService (the ServiceContract). For reasons of simplicity the example below contains only one method:

```
Imports System.ServiceModel

<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IemmbeeService

    <OperationContract>
    Function GetServiceId() As Guid
End Interface
```

This is the implementation:

```
Public Class emmbeeService
Implements IemmbeeService

    Private _serviceId As Guid

    Public Sub New()
        _serviceId = Guid.NewGuid
    End Sub

    Public Function GetServiceId() As Guid Implements IemmbeeService.GetServiceId
        Return _serviceId
    End Function
End Class
```

As you can see, the method GetServiceId returns a Guid which is created only once in the constructor.

This is how I create an instance of the service in the main application:

```
Public Function GetemmbeeService(endpoint As String) As IemmbeeService
        Dim es As IemmbeeService = New emmbeeService
        es = ChannelFactory(Of IemmbeeService).CreateChannel(New BasicHttpBinding(), New EndpointAddress(New Uri(endpoint)))
        Return es
End Function
```

Example of using the service:

```
Dim endpoint As String = ""http://myServer/emmbeeFramework/emmbeeService.svc"
emmbeeService = GetemmbeeService(endpoint)
Dim abc As Guid = emmbeeService.GetServiceId
```

This works well. I'm able to access the service and use all of its methods. But then I want to create a List(of T) for sharing purposes. Adding items to the list works fine, but when I want to access this list at another point of the application, the list results nothing.

I then tried the following:

```
Dim endpoint As String = ""http://myServer/emmbeeFramework/emmbeeService.svc"
emmbeeService = GetemmbeeService(endpoint)
Dim abc As Guid = emmbeeService.GetServiceId
Dim def As Guid = emmbeeService.GetServiceId
Dim ghi As Guid = emmbeeService.GetServiceId
```

I expected to recevice the same ServiceId three times (because I'm accessing only one single instance of the service and the ServiceId is only created a single time in the constructor of the service) - but instead the service returns three different guids.

What is my mistake? Or did I completely misunderstood WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

Using InstanceContextMode is the solution:

```
<ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.Single)>
Public Class emmbeeService
    Implements IemmbeeService

    ...
End Class
```